# how to find the max value of each store ID with the associated date?

Tags: sql, sum, max

I'm trying to find the max total quantity based on daily totals for each store ID with the associated date, but it's not showing up the way that I'm expecting

Here's what I tried:

```
select dateadd(dd,0,datediff(dd,0,Time)), storeid, max(qty_sum)
from
(
select time, storeid, sum(quantity) as qty_sum from table1
group by time, storeid, Quantity
) a  
group by dateadd(dd,0,datediff(dd,0,Time)), storeid
order by max(qty_sum) desc
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, but it's still giving me duplicate store IDs

Comment: Can you show us your schema (just the relevant parts) and some sample data? Use that schema and data to show us what you are expecting, and your actual result. To make it even easier for people to help, set it all up on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: You can use CTE in combination with Rank to get the data, but you haven't mentioned what DB you are using. The below code is for the SQL Server
`WITH DailyTotals AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST(Time AS DATE) AS Date,
        storeid,
        SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY storeid, CAST(Time AS DATE) ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC) AS rnk
FROM table1
GROUP BY CAST(Time AS DATE), storeid
)
SELECT 
Date,
storeid,
TotalQuantity FROM DailyTotals  WHERE rnk = 1;`
Like @Schwern said need minimum possible schema and data input and output to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think It might be due to the grouping and aggregation steps. To ensure a proper sum for each store ID on a daily basis, try this version:

```
SELECT CAST(Time AS DATE) AS DateOnly, storeid, MAX(qty_sum) AS MaxQuantity
FROM (
    SELECT Time, storeid, SUM(quantity) AS qty_sum
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY CAST(Time AS DATE), storeid
) a  
GROUP BY CAST(Time AS DATE), storeid
ORDER BY MaxQuantity DESC
```

This version aggregates the quantities by the store ID for each day and then identifies the maximum quantity for each store on a daily basis.